# The Database Connection is going high and also the RDS CPU is hitting 100% during the load testing

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-rds, load-testing

When doing the load testing on my application the AWS RDS CPU is hitting 100% and corresponding requests are getting errored out. The RDS is m4.2x.large. With the same configuration the things were fine until 2 weeks back. There are no infra changes done on the environment neither the application level changes. The whole load test used to go smooth until complete 2hrs until 2 weeks back. There are no specific exception apart from **GENERICJDBCEXCEPTION**.

All other necessary services are up and running on respective instances.

We are using SQL as Database Management System.

Is there any chance that this happens suddenly? How to resolve this? Suggestions are much appreciated. This has created many problems.

Monitoring the slow logs and resolving them did not solve the problem.

Should we upgrade the RDS to next version?

Does more data on then DB slows the Database?

We have modified the connection pool parameters also and tried it.

Answer (score 0):

With "load testing", are you able to finish one day's work in one hour?  That sounds great!  Or what do you mean by "load testing"?

Or are you trying to launch 200 threads in one second and they are stumbling over each other?  That's to be expected.  Do you really get 200 new connections in a single second?  Or is it spread out?

1 million queries per *day* is no problem.  A million queries all at once will fail.

Do not let your "load test" launch more threads than you can reasonably expect.  They will all pile up, and latency will suffer while the server is giving each thread an equal chance.

Meanwhile, use the slowlog to find the "worst" queries in production.  Then let's discuss the worst one or two -- Often an improved index makes that query work much faster, thereby no longer contributing to the train wreck.